Issues deploying to mainnet - on resume it just starts from 0% each time, never seems to progress
I have been trying to deploy a program to mainnet for several days now, on devnet it works fine and deploys in a few seconds, but on mainnet I just get:
Error: Data writes to account failed: Custom error: Max retries exceeded
I then dutifully resume with the buffer address:
solana program deploy --buffer program.json target/deploy/program.so
but the progress just starts from 0% each time, and I never get anywhere.
Am i going about this in the wrong way?  I'm on solana version 1.17.22, and have never had issues before (on devnet or mainnet).
Many Thanks

You are doing the right thing. Just currently the network is a bit overloaded and the cli does not do enough retires in the old version. The problem is being worked on.
There are some fixes for this in solana 1.18.8.
Try this:
sh -c "$(curl -sSfL https://release.solana.com/v1.18.11/install)"

This can also help:
https://twitter.com/stegaBOB/status/1775287709663109195
Or you can try to compile the cli with more retries like so:
https://twitter.com/sssionggg/status/1767961870269559027
